# d3 svg clipping mask on circle arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Can someone explain to me how to use clipping mask on the circle arc.

To explain what I'm doing. I have a circle and on this circle I add an arc that can be moved around. Now I would like to add like a linear gradient to this circle from left to right. But the gradient should only be seen on the arc, not the circle itself. Also I found one solution here https://www.freshconsulting.com/d3-js-gradients-the-easy-way/ but it's not what I want to do as my gradient should always be the same, but only the arc should display it. For example like this:
[image]

Comment: draw a white arc where you do **not** want to see the circle, your example has a radial gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would draw a masked circle with a gradient fill with d3.

```js
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500)

const defs = svg.append("defs")

const gradient = defs.append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "exampleGradient")

gradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "10%")
  .attr("stop-color", "white")

gradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "100%")
  .attr("stop-color", "red")

const mask = defs.append("mask")
  .attr("id", "donutMask")

mask.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 250)
  .attr("cy", 250)
  .attr("r", 150)
  .attr("fill", "white")

mask.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 250)
  .attr("cy", 250)
  .attr("r", 120)

const circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 149)
  .attr("cx", 250)
  .attr("cy", 250)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("mask", "url(#donutMask)")
  .attr("fill", "url(#exampleGradient)")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```